# IE и большие таблицы

Tags: веб-программирование, html, internet-explorer

Такая ситуация: на странице очень большая таблица, разбить на несколько нет возможности. Страница, соответственно, подгружается не сразу, а постепенно. При этом во всех браузерах, кроме IE, это выглядит нормально, а в IE сбивается вся вёрстка. Вёрстка табличная, это я тоже не могу изменить. Есть предположение, что IE таким образом реагирует на незакрытые теги таблицы (закрывающие теги пока не подгрузились). Подтягивать таблицу AJAX-ом - нежелательный вариант. Вопрос: можно ли как-нибудь заставить IE адекватно реагировать на подобную ситуацию?

Comment: выложите пример на http://jsfiddle.net/. Будем детально помогать Вам

Comment: Да, IE так реагирует на незакрытый тэг. сам сталкивался...

Answer (score 5):

```
if (stristr($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'], 'MSIE') ){
  header("Location: http://www.google.com/intl/ru/chrome/browser/");
}
```

Как вариант ;)